# Python: check for existing names but function not being triggered

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

Canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = 700, width = 1300, bg = "black")
Canvas.pack()
w = 0.8
h = 0.8
x=0.1
y=0.1
pw = 0.3
ph = 0.3
px = 0.35
py = 0.35
pName = ["Jack","Thomas"]
pScore = [0,0]
pList = [0,1]

def ncYes():
        menuPage()
        pName.append(playerName)
        pScore.append(0)
        pList.append(0)
def ncNo():
        notice("Please re enter a new name.")
        titlePage()

def popup(question,yes,no):
    popupFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "white")
    popupFrame.place(relwidth = pw, relheight = ph, relx = px, rely = py)
    question = tk.Label(popupFrame, text = question, fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 20 bold italic")
    title.pack()
    yes = tk.Button(popupFrame, text = "Yes", fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 15 bold",command=yes)
    yes.pack()
    no = tk.Button(popupFrame, text = "No", fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 15 bold",command=no)
    no.pack()

def notice(notice):
    noticeFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "white")
    noticeFrame.place(relwidth = pw, relheight = ph, relx = px, rely = py)
    notice = tk.Label(noticeFrame, text = notice, fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 20 bold italic")
    title.pack()
    okay = tk.Button(noticeFrame, text = "Okay", fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 15 bold",command=noticeFrame.destroy)
    okay.pack()

def nameCheck():
    for i in range(len(pName)) :
        if playerName == pName[i]:
            popup("Name already exist, is this your name?",ncYes,ncNo)
        else:
            if i == range(len(pName)):
                popup("Do you wanna create a new name?",ncYes,ncNo)


def menuPage():
    menuFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "white")
    menuFrame.place(relwidth = w, relheight = h, relx = x, rely = y)
    title = tk.Label(menuFrame, text = "Typing practice", fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 30 bold italic")
    title.pack()
    titlebtn = tk.Button(menuFrame, text = "back", fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 30 bold",command=titlePage)
    titlebtn.pack()

def titlePage():
    titleFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "white")
    titleFrame.place(relwidth = w, relheight = h, relx = x, rely = y)
    title = tk.Label(titleFrame, text = "Typing practice", fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 50 bold italic")
    title.pack()
    playerName = tk.Entry(titleFrame, text = "Your name", fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 30 italic")
    playerName.pack()
    start = tk.Button(titleFrame, text = "Start", fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 30 bold",command=menuPage)
    start.pack()

titleFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "white")
titleFrame.place(relwidth = w, relheight = h, relx = x, rely = y)
title = tk.Label(titleFrame, text = "Typing practice", fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 50 bold italic")
title.pack()
playerName = tk.Entry(titleFrame, text = "Your name", fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 30 italic")
playerName.pack()
start = tk.Button(titleFrame, text = "Start", fg = "black", bg = "gray", font = "Arial 30 bold",command=nameCheck)
start.pack()


 






warmUp = tk.Button(root, text = "Warmup", padx = 10, pady = 5, fg = "white", bg="black")
warmUp.pack()
quit = tk.Button(root, text = "Quit", padx = 10, pady = 5, fg = "white", bg="black", command = root.destroy)
quit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

hi guys, I am not sure why the nameCheck function is not being triggered.
I didn't put much effort into designing so it looks bad.
I used tkinter.

The start button in the titleFrame is supposed to trigger the nameCheck function that checks the playerName(in title frame entry) against pName(list).

Do I have to create a separate variable outside the function to store the playerName?

By the way, I am very new to coding, just found out what def is today. So please explain your code in detail, Thank you(^-^).

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code to the minimum necessary. There's a lot of code unrelated to the question being asked. See [mcve].

Comment: `playerName` is a widget.  It is NOT the text that the user typed into the widget (that would be retrieved via `playerName.get()`, and therefore will never be equal to any of the names in your list.

Comment: How do you know that the function is not triggered?  Did you try printing something to the console at the beginning of the function to see whether it is executed or not?

Answer (score -1):

The button command extension is on a diffrent line as so

```
btnRead=tk.Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Insert GUI", 
                command=getTextInput)
```

Comment: You know that when python compiles it to python bytecode it will be the same. Most new lines/white spaces (that aren't part of the indentation) get removed. Putting it on another line doesn't do anything